# What might cause Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) to throw a ClassCastException?

Tags: java, collections, comparator, classcastexception, comparable

I am calling Collections.sort() on an ArrayList using a Comparator that I declared earlier.

```
ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
Comparator<Employee> comparator = new Comparator<Employee>() {

  public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
    return o1.getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.getName().toLowerCase());
  }

};

...

Collections.sort(list, comparator);
```

For some reason, sort is trying to cast the elements of my ArrayList as Comparables, even though I passed a Comparator. Why might this be happening?

If it's of any use, here is my stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.ClassCastException: processing.app.EmployeeManager$PrettyOkayEmpolyee cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
    at foobar.Main.doSomeSorting(Main.java:140)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Without seeing code it's going to be awfully hard to tell you what's wrong.  Post the definition of both `Flub` and the comparator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Comparator` you passed is probably  `null`.

The Javadoc states:

> @param `c` the comparator to determine the order of the list.  A `null` value indicates that the elements' *natural ordering* should be used.

So it's going to assume the arguments are `Comparable` if the `Comparator` is `null`. The code in `Arrays.sort` is consistent with this. I think it really ought to throw a NPE if the `Comparator` is `null`, but it's part of the contract of the method and so can't be changed.

Comment: ...and it is! I would have expected a NullPointerException. Silly me.

Comment: @ColinD Thank you. I spent an hour following my code around, confirming that I had indeed supplied a Comparator to the TreeSet I was using, and only your answer here made me check that it was not in fact null. I was stupidly declaring a static comparator **after** the static singleton instance of the class. So the singleton was seeing a null value for the Comparator at time of construction of the TreeSet.