# Is using Classes as keys of a Map a bad idea?

Tags: java, exception, comparable

I have a use-case where I want to log different Strings depending on the type of the `Exception` raised. To accomplish this, I wrote a `Map` which maps a `Class` to a `String`. And I am checking if the raised `Exception` is an instance of any of the Classes in the map, if it is I log the corresponding String stored with it.

Is using a `Class` as a key of a `Map` a bad idea? I am using SonarLint for static code analysis and it complains that I am using something as a key for a `Map` which does not implement `Comparable`. How bad is it? Is there a better approach to tackle my use case?

Sample code -

```java
Map<Class<? extends Exception>, String> map = Map.of(A.class, "Log A", B.class, "Log B", C.class, "Log C");
map
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().isInstance(raisedException))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresentOrElse(
        entry -> log.warn(entry.getValue()),
        () -> log.warn("Unknown exception class: {}.", raisedException.getClass()));
```

SonarLint rule - https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-6411

Comment: For `HashMap` this is pretty fine. For `TreeMap` - this is not

Comment: Why do you think this would or could be a bad idea? The code you used should not trigger RSPEC-6411 IMHO, because that map implementation doesn't use a `Comparable` (and looking at the link, I'd say Sonar is even wrong). That said, if you're using Java 21, using a switch with pattern matching using instanceof might be the better choice (haven't worked with it enough to make a good judgement of that though). I think using a `Map` here is a bit dubious, as you don't really use any of the benefits of a map (you're basically treating it as a list of key value pairs with this code).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel `HashMap` can resolve hash collisions using `Comparable`, see the [`HashMap` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html): _when keys are Comparable, this class may use comparison order among keys to help break ties_. It can use comparison if many keys resolve to the same bucket to put the entries for a bucket into a tree instead of a list.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Ah, I'll delete my second comment then. I didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the OP is indeed not using the benefits of a map, but that’s not the problem of the map here, but the Stream operation. This could easily be fixed by using, e.g. `Stream.<Class<?>> iterate(raisedException.getClass(), Exception.class::isAssignableFrom, Class::getSuperclass) .map(map::get).filter(Objects::nonNull) .findFirst() .ifPresentOrElse(log::warn, () -> log.warn("Unknown exception class: {}.", raisedException.getClass()));` (or an equivalent loop which likely is more readable)

Comment: This SonarLint rule is a textbook example of *premature optimization*. Why should the developer waste time to implement `Comparable` for a key type (which isn’t even possible for all types, `Class` being one example), just for a hypothetical scenario of a hash collision? Especially as A) hash collisions are very unlikely for three `Class` keys and B) the immutable `Map` returned by `Map.of(…)` doesn’t even benefit from implementing `Comparable`, as that’s an implementation detail of OpenJDK’s  `HashMap` and `ConcurrentHashMap`. But well, it’s not the first questionable SonarLint rule…

Comment: @Holger. You pointed (and also Mark Rotteveel, thanks!) that I am not using the benefits of a Map. My use case is indeed to store key value pairs, I thought that's what a Map is for. What am I missing? Can you point me to a knowledge resource on this? What would be a better way to store key value pairs if not a Map?

Comment: Also, @Holger why is using `Stream.iterate` as you suggested above better than using `Map.entrySet().stream()`?

Comment: Your `Map.entrySet().stream()` approach iterates over the map, testing each key. My alternative calls the `get` method of the `Map`, using the lookup algorithm of the map. The iteration is only necessary if the exception has a subtype of a key. But the type hierarchy is short and fixed while the map may grow arbitrarily in the future. In other words, the performance of your approach depends on the map size while mine has a constant overhead. That’s “using the benefits of a map”, using the efficient lookup operation.

Comment: @Holger thanks for explaining. Can't say I fully understood what you said. I am a novice to Java but it's definitely a good starting point. I'll play around with these two code samples and run some benchmarks to get clarity. Thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256363/discussion-between-dashwoodice9-and-holger).

Answer (score 1):

**Is using a Class as a key of a Map a bad idea?**

Not at all, Map keys should always be a derived data type. Even though we are passing a Primitive data type it will be upcasted to the respective [Wrapper type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994068/wrapper-class-in-java#:%7E:text=Wrapper%20classes%20are%20used%20to,when%20an%20object%20is%20required.&text=The%20general%20idea%20of%20a,class%20or%20some%20other%20functionality.).

**Is it ok to use something as a key for a Map which does not implement Comparable?**

[Comparable or Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420223/what-is-the-difference-between-compare-and-compareto) are interfaces that are used on a class to ensure that the class is providing a comparison mechanism when a collection of the same is being sorted. This will come into the picture only when you are trying to sort your Map ([TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)).

A few of the in-built classes are already implementing the above interfaces, but `Exception` classes won't usually implement it because they won't be used in a sorting scenario. So, you can ignore that warning, it is giving a warning for the possibility that if your `map` is initialized to a `TreeMap` it can cause a [ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867161/what-might-cause-collections-sortlistt-comparator-super-t-to-throw-a-cla).

**PS: We will supply a reference of a class to a Map, we cannot supply a class to a Map** ([Class vs Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224517/what-are-classes-references-and-objects))